# AngularJS 1, Ng-repeat, data in array from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have major issues to repeat my data from firebase. I have an array that has the data from Firebase but I can't repeat it somehow.

My loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < snapshot.numChildren(); i++) {

    var _lat = snapshot.child(i).child('Geo').child(0).val();
    var _long = snapshot.child(i).child('Geo').child(1).val();
    var _Title = snapshot.child(i).child('Title').val();

    filler[i] = snapshot.child(i).val();
}
```

'filler' array data in json:

```
[
  null,
  {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "Geo": [
      -7.090910999999999,
      107.668887
    ],
    "Location": [
      "West Java, Indonesia"
    ],
    "Title": "test",
    "status": "Open",
    "user": "sadawdawd4-e45a-4d7a-a9c7-83fad641aa62",
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "Geo": [
      34.506668,
      -81.948334
    ],
    "Location": [
      "Lund null"
    ],
    "Title": "test",
    "status": "Open",
    "user": "9d12dds8-9c5f-40d9-a458-aasd3d2121d",
  }
]
```

I dont now if is because of the null, at the beginning and I don't know why I get null.

Then I do the following in the view:

```
ng-repeat="item in filler"
```

and I can't see anything in the view, yes I am very newbie regarding this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your code before for `(i = 1; i < snapshot.numChildren(); i++) {`?

Comment: Your filler has nothing stored on the index 0, so maybe that's breaking your code?